# Facebook graph API v2.5: How to search for Game Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am reading Facebook [Search protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search). But I don't see an option to search for a [game group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups/v2.5)(a group that belongs to game or application). I did how ever found a way to search for simple a groups:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/search?
    q={your-query}&type=group
```

How can I search for **game groups**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think that´s possible, but shouldn´t you always know the groups in your game anyway? You can just store the ID/details right after creating it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/game-groups/v2.5#create_group

Comment: I believe I will have 100+ new groups a day. It's hard to make the synchronization from client side, and I am not sure if I want to store it in the backend.

Comment: why is that hard? it´s a lot easier to just store the details right when they are created, than using a search api. and a LOT faster too, the facebook api is definitely slower than your own database. in any case, this would be the best solution, even if it would be possible to use the search api, you should do that - caching is important.

Comment: You think my back end is better? You didn't saw the budget lol. Any way I understand what you are saying. I guess I try.

Comment: of course it is better. no problem with api limits, a LOT faster. the budget is always low, but you should always aim for the best solution ;)